# take last filled cell in every row in a data.frame R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that has 500 rows and at least a dozen columns per row. Some rows have a lot more columns. What I want to do is to create a variable that contains the contents of the last filled cell, per row.

dput(head(calls_with_overlap, 10))

```
    A      B        C       D
1. aknasd kasdknsd kasdkas kasdpa
2. asdhad none
3. apihsd piahsdas ashpidapishd phasd askdn wads
4. kasdas none
```

What I tried so far is:

```
if (calls_with_overlap$Overlap[10] = "none") 
{
Ending <- TRUE
} 
else (Ending <- FALSE)
 if (Ending == FALSE) 
   {
  for (q in 1:1024) #max is 1024 columns. perhaps not best way for number of columns.
  {
   EndingCell <- c(10 + q)
   EndingCellcontents <- calls_with_overlap[h,EndingCell] # h is from an outer loop, going through each row. 
     if (EndingCellcontents != ""){ 
       EndingCellcontents[q] <-    EndingCellcontents}
       last  <-  length(EndingCellcontents)
       last<-  EndingCellcontents[last]
      }}
```

I would like "last" to contain the last filled cell in each row, unless it says "none". Starting from column B.

i.e. in this case

```
last
[1] kasdpa
[2] wads
```

Apologies if this is a nooby question, but I'm teaching myself programming from scratch.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't mean like that?

Comment: You can't have a data frame that looks like this.  IT has to be rectangular.  Are the empty cells at the end filled somehow?  NAs or ""?  If you follow ttmaccer's directions it will be easier to help.  So using the mtcars set: `dput(head(mtcars, 10))`  Just replace mtcars with the name of your data set.

Comment: the empty cells are blank. It's an imported file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited: mistaken rows and columns

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("r","","z"),B=c("w","",""))
df
  A B
1 r w
2    
3 z  
v <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x[rev(which((x!="")==TRUE))[1]])
[1] "w" NA  "z"
v[!is.na(v)]
[1] "w" "z"
```

Comment: edited: you fixed it already. that's very close, but in this case, I would want it ordered w then z.

Comment: Thank you Julius, works like a charm. I wonder how long it takes to learn as much as this...

Comment: You are welcome. That is not as hard as it looks, but pay attention to `apply`, it would help you a lot. `which` is simple and helpful, and all the rest is putting it all together.